# Constructing unordered_map always copies unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17

For some reason, when trying to construct an unordered map (specifically by a pair), the map tried to copy the unique_ptr in the pair instead of move it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an example (updated):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

class pointed
{
    bool x;
    int y;
public:
    float key;
    pointed( float key, bool x, int y ): x(x), y(y)
    { }
};

class test
{
    std::unordered_map< float, std::unique_ptr< pointed > > my_map;
public:
    template< typename... pointed_construction_t >
    test( pointed_construction_t &&... pointed_parameter_pack ):
        my_map
        {
            std::move
            (
                std::make_pair
                ( 
                    pointed_parameter_pack.key,
                    std::move
                    (
                        std::make_unique< pointed >
                        (
                            std::forward< pointed_construction_t >
                            ( 
                                pointed_parameter_pack 
                            )
                        ) 
                    )
                )
            )...
        }
    { }
};

int main( )
{
    float key = 2.f, key2 = 4.f;
    bool x = true, x2 = false;
    int y = 0, y2 = -1;
    test t( pointed( key, x, y ), pointed( key2, x2, y2 ), pointed( 6.f, false, 500 ) );
}
```

> error: use of deleted function
>
> note: declared here
>
> 406 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

Comment: You don't need to `std::move()` something that is already an rvalue. Both of the `std::move()`s in your example are unnecessary at best (and potentially harmful at worst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `my_map{...}` is list-initialization and the compiler finds the `std::initializer_list` constructor of `std::unordered_map`. This constructs an initializer list which holds an array of `const` elements. So your elements can't be moved from the list to the map.

You'll have to go inside the constructor and emplace the elements of the pair:

```c++
test(int key, pointed_construction_t&&... pointed_parameter_pack) {
  map.emplace(key,
              std::make_unique<pointed>(std::forward<pointed_construction_t>(
                  pointed_parameter_pack)...));
}
```

With your new update I am able to understand what you want. Use a fold expression so that `emplace` is called for every `pointed` argument.

```c++
(map.emplace(key,
         std::make_unique<pointed>(
             std::forward<pointed_construction_t>(pointed_parameter_pack))),
...);
```

Comment: @nowi No, it finds the `std::initializer_list` constructor of `unordered_map`, which constructs an `std::initializer_list<std::pair<int const, std::unique_ptr<pointed>>>`. The `std::initializer_list` stores its elements as `const`, so you can't move the pair from the list to the map.

Comment: @nowi In your original example `test t{key, x, y}` calls the constructor template that you defined, so you are correct about that. When I talked about using `{}`, I was referring to what you wrote in the member initializer list (`: my_map{ std::move(...) }`). You used the curly braces, so the compiler found the initializer list constructor and constructed an initializer list with the pair you made. My solution addresses that and corrects the issue.

Comment: @nowi It is indeed an oversight. Doing it in the constructor would only cost you a default-construction of the `unordered_map` which shouldn't be a problem. AFAIK there is no clean alternative way to initialize the map without the constructor. You would have to return a new map from a function and move it into `map` like so: `: my_map( [&]{ unordered_map<...> m; m.emplace(...); return m; }() )`. Not really worth it IMO.

Comment: @nowi Yes, using the lambda and expanding it with `...` would be one way of doing it.

Comment: @nowi Okay, now I think I understand what you're trying to do. Please see my update and tell me if it works for your new example.

Comment: @nowi Only if it makes sense. If your program requires shared access to the resource then `shared_ptr` is the right tool. If you're only using it to get past that `intiializer_list` hurdle, then in the long run it may not be worth it. `shared_ptr` uses more memory than `unique_ptr`s because it has to allocate a control block and use reference counting. If you really want to write everything in the member initializer list, as I said, you can put the code into a lambda and return a dummy map that you can move into the main map. [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ccbc5d4cd1c453b4).